# how to let splash page full screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, fullscreen, splash-screen

how to let the splash page full screen in flutter?
i got how to set splash page in [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#updating-the-launch-screen)

```
<resources>
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
         Flutter draws its first frame -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Android module go to the `app/src/main/res/values`

Open up the file name `styles.xml`

Inside this file you will have a below code that is your custom style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You need add the below line in it:

```
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Like Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Once you add the above line app stays in fullscreen mode for the entire life-cycle. To disable it you need to define a normal theme to be applied to FlutterActivity after the launch screen is gone and in that theme add the above line with value "false".

Like Below:

```
 <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: It's not automatically removed after first frame. App stays in fullscreen forever. How to disable it after splash screen?

Comment: Didn't work for me. Image is still not fullscreen :(

Comment: same for me, not in full screen mode

Answer (score -2):

Put your image inside the drawable folder and call it in src

`<item><bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash" /> </item>`